# SQL error: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql query

```
SELECT sites.id, sites.url, GROUP_CONCAT(categories.name,"|",
    categories.color SEPARATOR ",") AS categories
FROM sites
LEFT JOIN categories_data ON sites.id = categories_data.sites_id
LEFT JOIN categories ON categories_data.categories_id = categories.id
WHERE sites.deleted=0 
AND WHERE categories.deleted=0 
AND WHERE categories_data.deleted=0 
GROUP BY sites.id
```

I get this error:

```
Database_Exception [ 1064 ]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
the right syntax to use near 'WHERE categories.deleted=0 AND WHERE 
categories_data.deleted=0 GROUP BY sites.id' at line 5 [ SELECT sites.id, 
sites.url, GROUP_CONCAT(categories.name,"|",categories.color SEPARATOR ",") 
AS categories FROM sites LEFT JOIN categories_data ON sites.id = 
categories_data.sites_id LEFT JOIN categories ON 
categories_data.categories_id = categories.id WHERE sites.deleted=0 
AND WHERE categories.deleted=0 AND WHERE categories_data.deleted=0 GROUP BY 
sites.id ]
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: You have multiple `WHERE` keywords.  The second should just be `AND` instead of `AND WHERE`

Comment: This error means that the SQL statement is so malformed that the parser doesn't even try to give you specific advice on how to fix it.  The error is the MySQL parser telling you to read the manual on how to write a valid SQL select statement: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: Is Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884522/mysql-error-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-check-the-manual-that-corresponds-to

Answer (score 6, accepted):

because you have three `WHERE` clause. If you have multiple condition you need to separate  them using condition operator,

```
SELECT ...
FROM   ... JOIN ...
WHERE  sites.deleted = 0 AND 
       categories.deleted = 0 AND 
       categories_data.deleted = 0 
GROUP  BY sites.id
```